# How can I determine the length of time since the last screen refresh on X11?

Tags: linux, refresh, x11

I'm trying to debug a laggy machine vision camera by writing text timestamps to a terminal window and then observing how long it takes for the camera to 'detect' the screen change. My monitor has a 60hz refresh rate, so the screen is updated every ~17ms. Is there a way to determine at what point within that 17ms window the refresh timer currently is for an X11 application.

**EDIT:** After wrestling with the problem for nearly a day, I think the real question I should have asked was how to generate a visual signal that was sufficiently fast to test the camera images. My working hypothesis was that the camera was buffering frames before transmitting them, as the video stream seemed to lag behind other synchronised digital events (in this case, output signals to a robotic controller)

Comment: An X11 application knows nothing about monitor refresh.

Comment: Agreed, but surely the server does, that's the information I need in order to try and isolate the supposed 'latency' in the camera input

Comment: A simple program that displays a timestamp can easily update the video buffer 20000 times a second, with an `XSync` after each frame. That's on old clunky hardware like I have. The video card should update the display at its nominal refresh rate.

Comment: My requirements have been addressed using the keyboard leds but your answer was exactly what I was looking for originally (XSync), if you create an answer to that effect, I will accept.

Answer (score 0):

'xrefresh' is a tool which can trigger a refresh event on an X server. It does this by painting a global window of a specified color and then removing it, causing all subsequent windows to repaint. Even with this, I was still getting very inconsistent results when trying to correlate the captured frames against the monitor output, no matter what I tried to do, the video stream seemed to lag behind what I expected the monitor state to be. This could mean that either the camera was slow to capture or the monitor was slow to update. Fortunately, I eventually hit upon the idea of using the keyboard leds to verify the synchronicity of the camera frames. ('xset led' and 'xset -led'). This showed me immediately that in fact my computer monitor was slow to update, instead of the camera lagging behind.